# Using Random Number Table

Tags: sampling, random-variable, random-generation

In a random number table, the random numbers are given as first thousand, second thousand, third thousand, and so on.

Every thousand has 25 rows and 1 to 4, 5 to 8 up to 37–40 columns.

Suppose I have to draw a sample of size 40 from a population of 10000, and I am using the 1 to 5 column for selecting the random numbers.

When the 1 to 5 column of first thousand has been finished, but I have not arrived at my desired sample size yet, what is the process to select the random numbers?

Will I need to go to the `column 6 to 10` of the `first thousand`? Or go to the `column 1 to 5` of the `second thousand`?

Another table [here](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=random+number+table&rlz=1C2RNLE_enBD516BD516&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=qQQxUum6NYb_iAez5oGYBQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1241&bih=571&dpr=1#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=N0qdQ_0cr1X5QM%3A%3BN0u7__8ASlk47M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fapps.who.int%252Fmedicinedocs%252Fdocuments%252Fwhozip14e%252Fp06.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.who.int%252Fmedicinedocs%252Fen%252Fd%252FJwhozip14e%252F9.html%3B1000%3B745) is the 1st page. If I decide to use the 1 to 5 number columns, when the 1 to 5 number columns of the 1st page are finished, will I move to the 1 to 5 number columns of the 2nd page or stay on the 1st page using 6 to 10 columns?

Comment: Is there anyway for you to show us what the table looks like?  perhaps a link or image of it?  I am having a hard time visualizing it.

Comment: Also, when you say a population of 10,000 do you mean that your want to sample values between 0 - 10,000 or am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you using a random number table?

Comment: @BabakP I have to use table in exam hall. In practical exam i may be allow to use software.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest watching this YouTube video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9v2d-9VfEK4

in order to understand exactly how to use a random number table to answer your question.  The video show you how to select random numbers between 0 and 58 but you can follow the same routine to sample your random values.

I assume when you say a population of 10,000 you mean that your random values can be any value in the range 0  - 10,000 (correct me if I am wrong) and so you would pick a random starting spot in the your table and starting going down the rows and moving over one column at a time as you finish all the rows until you reach your desired sample size of 40 random values.

## Edit:

So based on the table you provided above now, you could use columns 1 - 5 and work your way down accepting numbers (using all 5 columns) that fell in the range 0 - 10,000.  Once you are down with all the rows you would move over and then use columns 2 - 6 and proceed in similar fashion. However, if you exclude 10,000 then you could more efficiently use columns 1 - 4 and when done with those move over to 2 - 5 and so on.

Comment: you are right. the sample values can be determined in the range $00001-10000$

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I apologize. I haven't understood the point. Using 1-5 columns and then using `2-`6. Why not 6-10 ? [In this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53MVU07j6dY) , once they have taken three digits of 1st,2nd,and 3rd column, they move on the next three column starting at #4 column for generating the next random number.